# Browser Autocomplete Naming Conventions and Testing

Tags: browser, autocomplete, naming-conventions

Is there a comprehensive list of browser autocomplete naming conventions somewhere?  I would like to know what to name form fields and such so the browser can autocomplete them, and so I can decide if I want to use the autocomplete feature, or if I should rename the fields to something else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would advise you to choose rather unique names for your fields. It is very annoying when FireFox gathers all "Email" inputs from all sites I visit and then shows them all in a long list whenever I try to enter my email somewhere else.

If somebody will use your PC to quickly check their mails they will know all your other email names in an instant. Not good.

Comment: If you don't want autocomplete, just disable it in your browser.

Comment: This function must be done properly and distinguish between the sites. Otherwise it's a lazy job not done properly.

Comment: Completely disagree! Why is that annoying! That's the whole point of auto-complete so when you visit other sites you don't need to enter them in! For auto-completion of an email address for a single site - that's what a browser cookie is for